# Match sheet1's column1 cell value with sheet2's column1 cell value if matches then match another

Tags: excel

EXCEL QUESTION

I'm having 2 sheets. 
In 1st sheet I have:

```
CUSTOMERS NAME, SPOUSE NAME, PLACE, AMOUNT
```

In 2nd sheet I have:

```
CUSTOMERS NAME, SPOUSE NAME, PLACE, AMOUNT(SIMILAR/DIFFERENT FROM 1ST SHEET)
```

I want to match sheet 2nd customer name to sheet 1st customer name, if matches then match sheet 2nd spouse name with sheet 1st spouse name, if matches then match sheet 2nd place with sheet 1st place, if matches then copy sheet 1st place to sheet 2nd's column F

Comment: Sample data and example of what exactly you expect would be helpful.

Comment: INDEX() & MATCH() will do the matching and finding. There are several posts on here using that approach - have a search.